# Ember-CLI uses wrong path for jQuery and QUnit

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using a fresh install of ember-cli with the following versions:

```
~/Projects/ember_tut > ember s
version: 1.13.13
node: 4.2.1
npm: 2.14.10
os: darwin x64
```

bower.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "ember-tut",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.13.11",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.0.6",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "0.2.1",
    "ember-data": "1.13.15",
    "ember-load-initializers": "0.1.7",
    "ember-qunit": "0.4.16",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.20",
    "jquery": "^1.11.3",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.4.0",
    "qunit": "~1.20.0",
    "pretender": "~0.10.1",
    "lodash": "~3.7.0",
    "Faker": "~3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Immediately after running `ember new ember_test`:

```
~/Projects/ember_tut > ember s
version: 1.13.13
Livereload server on http://localhost:49154
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/sms/Projects/ember_tut/tmp/concat_with_maps-input_base_path-pmZyxQ2F.tmp/0/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/sms/Projects/ember_tut/tmp/concat_with_maps-input_base_path-pmZyxQ2F.tmp/0/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:849:18)
    at ConcatWithMaps.keyForFile (/Users/sms/Projects/ember_tut/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-sourcemap-concat/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:90:20)
    at Array.map (native)
    at ConcatWithMaps.CachingWriter._conditionalBuild (/Users/sms/Projects/ember_tut/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-sourcemap-concat/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:112:65)
    at /Users/sms/Projects/ember_tut/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-sourcemap-concat/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/read_compat.js:61:34
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/sms/Projects/ember_tut/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:493:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/sms/Projects/ember_tut/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:505:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/Users/sms/Projects/ember_tut/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:476:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/Users/sms/Projects/ember_tut/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
```

It's looking for `jquery.js` in `bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js` but it's really in `bower_components/jquery/jquery-1.11.3/dist/jquery.js`.

This is easily "fixed" by creating a symlink in `bower_components/jquery/` to `bower_components/jquery/jquery-1.11.3/dist`, but that's awfully klunky, and I'm wondering what the right way to address it is.

Comment: Please review the spelling of your title.

Comment: What does your `bower.json` file look like? Have you tried doing a `bower cache clean` followed by a `bower install`?

Comment: Thanks for the correction torazaburo. nem, I completely uninstalled bower and ember-cli, then reinstalled, with the same issue. Added bower.json to the question.

Comment: My copy of jquery 1.11.3 from bower does indeed have a bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js Can you post the .bower.json inside bower_components/jquery? Especially interested in "version" and "main" fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that removing all npm and bower caches, then reinstalling everything worked, which makes me think that nem's suggestion in the comments was pretty close:

```
npm cache clear && bower cache clean && rm -rf node_modules bower_components && npm install && bower install
```